# Creating update user profile page using PHP MySql

Tags: javascript, php, html, css

I have managed to go ahead with my user update page and it all seems to be fine at the form I had it reading the current details from logged in user when i clicked submit it says submit successful, then I am stuck with this page can't go back, I don't know if it worked and cannot see any error messages or any that i can see.

I am very new to coding so sorry if any silly mistake i missed out on... someone help me please....

Here is my PHP

```
<?php

include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
session_start();
if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
$username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
else {
echo "You have not signed in";
}

// Initialize any variables that the page might echo
$firstname = "";
$surname = "";
$u = "";
$weight = "";
$height = "";
// Make sure the _GET username is set, and sanitize it
if(isset($_GET["u"])){
    $u = preg_replace('#[^a-z0-9]#i', '', $_GET['u']);
} else {
    header("location: index.php");
    exit(); 
}

// Select the member from the users database table
$sql = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username='$u' AND activated='1' LIMIT 1";
$user_query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
// check if the user exists in the database
$numrows = mysqli_num_rows($user_query);
if($numrows < 1){
   echo "That user does not exist or is not yet activated, press back";
exit(); 
}

while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($user_query, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
$firstname = $row["firstname"];
$surname = $row["surname"];
$weight = $row["weight"];
$height = $row["height"];
$profile_id = $row["id"];
$u = $row["u"];
}

// this is the calculation of the BMI index
//$BMI = ($weighteight / ($heighteight * $heighteight))* 10000;


if($firstname =="" || $surname == ""|| $weight == "" || $height == ""){
echo "The form submission is missing values.";
    exit();
} else {    
    $p_hash = md5($p);
    // Add user info into the database table for the main site table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO users (firstname, surname, weight, height)       
                           VALUES('$fn','$sn','$w','$h')";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql); 
    $uid = mysqli_insert_id($db_conx);
    // Establish their row in the useroptions table
    $sql = "INSERT INTO useroptions (id, username, background) VALUES ('$uid','$u','original')";
    $query = mysqli_query($db_conx, $sql);
    // Create directory(folder) to hold each user's files(pics, MP3s, etc.)
    if (!file_exists("user/$u")) {
        mkdir("user/$u", 0755);
    }
    // Email the user their activation link
    $to = "$e";                          
    $from = "k1003140@kingston.ac.uk";
    $subject = 'studentnet.kingston.ac.uk/k1003140';
    $message = '<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta charset="UTF-8"><title>yoursitename Message</title></head><body style="margin:0px; font-family:Tahoma, Geneva, sans-serif;"><div style="padding:10px; background:#333; font-size:24px; color:#CCC;"><a href="http://www.yoursitename.com"><img src="http://www.yoursitename.com/images/logo.png" width="36" height="30" alt="yoursitename" style="border:none; float:left;"></a>yoursitename Account Activation</div><div style="padding:24px; font-size:17px;">Hello '.$u.',<br /><br />Click the link below to activate your account when ready:<br /><br /><a href="https://studentnet.kingston.ac.uk/k1003140/activation.php?id='.$uid.'&u='.$u.'&e='.$e.'&p='.$p_hash.'">Click here to activate your account now</a><br /><br />Login after successful activation using your:<br />* E-mail Address: <b>'.$e.'</b></div></body></html>';
    $headers = "From: $from\n";
    $headers .= "MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
    $headers .= "Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1\n";
    mail($to, $subject, $message, $headers);
    echo "signup_success";



    exit();
}
exit();
?>
```

Here is my Javascript code

```
<script>
function signup(){
var u = _("username").value;
var fn = _("firstname").value;
var sn = _("surname").value;
var w = _("weight").value;
var h = _("height").value;
var e = _("email"). value;
var status = _("status");
if(fn == "" || sn == "" || w == "" || h == ""|| g == ""){
    status.innerHTML = "Fill out all of the form data";
} else {
    _("signupbtn").style.display = "none";
    status.innerHTML = 'please wait ...';
    var ajax = ajaxObj("POST", "signup.php");
    ajax.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(ajaxReturn(ajax) == true) {
            if(ajax.responseText != "signup_success"){
                status.innerHTML = ajax.responseText;
                _("signupbtn").style.display = "block";
            } else {
                window.scrollTo(0,0);
                _("signupform").innerHTML = "OK "+u+", check your email inbox and junk mail box at <u>"+e+"</u> in a moment to complete the sign up process by activating your account. You will not be able to do anything on the site until you successfully activate your account.";
            }
        }
    }
    ajax.send("fn="+fn+"&sn="+sn+"&w="+w+"&h="+h+);
}
}
```

here i added some more of my code to see the HTML

```
    <body>
<?php include_once("template_pageTop.php"); ?>
    <div id="pageMiddle">  
    <form name="signupform" id="signupform" onsubmit="return false;">  
    <div id="usernamecss"><?php echo $u; ?></div>
    <p><b>Is the viewer the page owner, logged in and verified? <?php echo $isOwner; ?></b></p>   
    <p>First Name: <input type="text" name="firstname" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" size="35" maxlength="15" value='<?=$firstname?>'></p>
    <p>Surname: <input type="text" name="surname" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" size="35" maxlength="15" value='<?=$surname?>'></p>
    <p>Weight: <input type="text" name="weight" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" size="35" maxlength="15" value='<?=$weighteight?>'></p>
    <p>Height: <input type="text" name="height" onfocus="emptyElement('status')" size="35" maxlength="15" value='<?=$heighteight?>'></p>
    <button id="signupbtn" onclick="signup()">Create Account</button>
    </div>
    </form>
        <?php include_once("template_pageBottom.php"); ?>
        <span id="status"></span>
</body>
```

Comment: Your insert query has specified more columns, than inserted. Are they default null?

Comment: I fixed that still it goes to signup success straight without giving me the HTML @RoyalBg

Comment: There are many `exit()` lines that would not run or probably shouldn't be there. Why did you put so many `exit()` calls?

Comment: Have a look at your post (using firebug console for example) and look what php echoes to it. If you can't debug, add more echoes to see where its is stuck. Especialy here: header("location: index.php");

Answer (score 0):

i can't write comment so i will write here
U should use session_start(); at the first line of the page and this may cause some problem try it

```
session_start();
include_once("php_includes/check_login_status.php");
```

Comment: I tried that it coming back with "The form submission is missing values" but i have not clicked anything or entered any data @robert

Comment: Note: The session_start() function must appear BEFORE the <html> tag:

Comment: and i always write my first line like this 

    <?php session_start();

Answer (score 0):

As I can see you are doing a POST in your ajax but are reacting to GET in your php.

Try to change:

```
if(isset($_GET["u"])){
```

to:

```
if(isset($_POST["u"])){
```

or:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST["u"])){
```